# I would like a hint on this problem regarding harmonic numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$$
((n+1)H_n - (n+1)) + H_{n+1} = (n+2)H_{n+1} - (n+2)
$$
I need to prove the above statement.

Comment: doesn't merely using the definition of $H_n$ work?

Comment: $H_{n+1}=H_n+1/(n+1)$

Comment: I should have added that I had gotten that far, but I can't figure what to do with that.

Comment: @Mark: cancel as many terms as you can.

Comment: Do you really need to prove it by induction? In my answer I assumed not.

Comment: It's part of an inductive proof ($H_1+H_2+...+H_n = (n+1)H_n - (n+1)$)

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I've now fully proven the statement.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Your identity is equivalent to

$$(n+1)(H_{n+1}-H_{n})=1,$$

which is something you can deduce by a simple algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like an idiot now (like always). Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $\ $ If $\rm\:f(n)\:$ satsifies a first-order recurrence $\rm\ \ f(n+1) = a\ f(n) + b\ $ then it may be used as a rewrite rule to reduce $\rm\ c_0\ f(n) + c_1\ f(n+1) + \:\cdots\: + c_k\ f(n+k)\ $ to the form $\rm\ d\ f(n) + e\:.\ $ Said in operator form, if $\rm \ S^2 = a\ S + b\ $ then $\rm\ f(S)\ \:mod\:\ (S^2-a\ S-b)\ =\ c\ S + d\ $ has degree 1, since one can eliminate $\rm\:S^n,\ n>2\ $ via the rewrite rule $\rm\: S^2 \to a\ S + b\:$. In essence one is employing the division / Euclidean algorithm to compute a remainder in a polynomial ring of operators. Precisely the same method works for solutions of any (monic) linear recurrence or differential equation.